# ARIA attributes for custom expand / collapse button in details / summary

Tags: html, wai-aria

I am styling a set of `<details>` + `<summary>` elements, and using a custom icon for the expand / collapse arrow instead of the default arrow provided by browers:

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <svg aria-*='???'>
      <use href=#chevron>
    </svg>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </summary>
</details>
```

Does the SVG icon need any ARIA labels? Alternatively, should it be hidden from screen readers entirely (relying on just the "open" attribute to be announced instead)?

Answer (score 1):

The actual icon doesn't matter to the screen reader.  It's just a picture that represents whether the section is open or closed.  What's important to the screen reader is the *state* of the details widget, analogous to [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded).  The icon itself should be hidden to screen readers (possibly via [`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden)).